# Using accept language header to guess user's country, if available

Tags: javascript, php, browser, craftcms

I want to use Javascript/PHP to determine if a user's browser has a country (locale variant) defined in the accept-language header.

Knowing that the contents of the accept-language header value can vary, and is not always accurate, is there a way to logically determine if a country present in the accept-language header string? And then extract that via JS?

For example, if a user's accept language header contains en-US, I would want to set a local variable="US".

My intial thought was to create a very large array of all accept header language and locale values and check against that, but that did not seem like a very efficient approach.

Comment: Use a simple split or regex to extract the 2nd part after the `-` (hyphen).

Comment: What does “language” have to do with “country”? My browser is set to request `en-US` with top priority, and neither am I in America, nor am I American. So what would you actually want to do with your “guess” now?

Comment: @cbroe although its not totally reliable (like in your case), the use-case we are building for is to use the locale of "US," in your case, to display pages aimed towards a United Stated audience, when the page loads. We will also allow the user to change this on the UI. But, we thought that would be a good starting point to try to infer that information about where the use is coming from (albiet not always correct)

Answer (score 0):

The `Accept-Language` header has a couple of formats it can take, [see the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language). Getting the preferred languages as a structured list (like an array sorted by q-factor) is just a matter of parsing that list in a way that is resilient to all the possible permutations of the header values.

Instead of trying to write this logic yourself, it's simpler to use a library built for this exact purpose, which will be better at handling all kinds of weird edge-cases. For example, [willdurand/Negotiation](https://github.com/willdurand/Negotiation) allows you to parse the `Accept-Language` header and match it to a list of locales supported by your site to find the best language to use.

You will have to do this on the server-side (in PHP). Once you know the language, you can pass that to client-side JavaScript in a number of ways. For example, you can use the [JS tag](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/tags.html#position) to include a piece of JavaScript in your page template that sets a global variable with the determined language.